# Almost there! How can I add another git status colour to bash prompt?

Tags: linux, git, bash, colors

This mostly works, I was able to add colour to my bash prompt based on the git status.  The (origin/master) will be green if everything is committed, if not then I know I haven't committed.  However I'm trying to add additional colours, like yellow for 'untracked changes' and red if I haven't done anything.

Here's what I've cobbled together so far from various posts in my .bashrc

Bash version: 4.3.48(1)-release

OS: Linux Mint 18.2

```
## trim to two dir depth
PROMPT_DIRTRIM=2

## green user@hostname, then blue dirs, then colours for git branch

COLOURGREEN="\033[01;32m"
COLOURBLUE="\033[01;34m"
COLOURPLAIN="\033[m"
COLOURRED="\033[1;31m"
COLOURYELLOW="\033[1;33m"

## This works fine on it's own, I see the (origin/master) in prompt
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

## green works when all files committed but not other colours
git_colour() {

    local gitstatus="$(git status 2> /dev/null)"

    if [[ ! $gitstatus =~ "working directory clean" ]]; then
        echo -e $COLOURRED
    elif [[ $gitstatus =~ "Untracked files:" ]]; then
        echo -e $COLOURYELLOW
    elif [[ $gitstatus =~ "nothing to commit" ]]; then
        echo -e $COLOURGREEN
    else
        echo -e $COLOURPLAIN
fi
}

## working export without colour on git
# Example: user@hostname ~/.../dir3/dir4 (origin/master)
# export PS1="\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w\[\033[m\]\$(parse_git_branch) $ "

## works only when green
export PS1="\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w\[\$(git_colour)\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[m\] $ "
```

Just a little help with git_colour() or if I've screwed up the bash colour codes?  Thanks

Comment: If your status is anything other than "working directory clean", you'll get red, won't you?

Comment: No I get green if clean otherwise it stays the same.  No other colours occur.  I'm trying different states of the git status to see but only the fully committed status makes the dir green.

Comment: I'm going to try reducing the if statement and rebuild it to confirm what's going on

Comment: Parsing the status message is extremely brittle. For example, newer git uses "working *tree* clean" instead of "directory". You should use something like `git status --porcelain` instead.

Comment: actually that works, changes the prompt back to white from blue

Comment: In git status --porcelain, ?? is new, A is staged, and committed says nothing and just repeats the prompt.  How do I test for this?  Do I use the : colon for a null result?

Comment: (Testing shows you're right about \033[m at least in Terminal - for some reason I have an explicit 0 in my color-variable settings, and I thought it was based on *something:* maybe xterm?) To test for a zero length string, use `test -n "$var"` or `test -z "$var"` (depending on the true or false value you want), or compare `"$var" == ""`, for instance. Note that `[ ... ]` is the same as `test ...`: both run the `test` program (built-in to the shell). You only need the double `[[` syntax for regular expression tests and other fancier tricks.

Comment: Fixed it.  That looked complicated so instead I redid the if statement to make the final else COLOURGREEN and used git status --porcelain to test for ?? and A respectively.  I now have a prompt that turns red, yellow, and green!  Thanks for your comments

Comment: FYI see [powerline shell](https://github.com/banga/powerline-shell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the git status --porcelain suggestion from Benjamin W and then redoing the if statement to put the COLOURGREEN as the final else, I now have a prompt that changes colour based on the git status!  Huzzah.  Change git_colour() above to:

```
git_colour() {


    local gitstatus="$(git status --porcelain 2> /dev/null)"

    if [[ $gitstatus =~ "??" ]]; then
        echo -e $COLOURRED  
    elif [[ $gitstatus =~ "A" ]]; then
        echo -e $COLOURYELLOW
    else
        echo -e $COLOURGREEN
    fi
}
```